# MQL4 code limiting number of open symbols

Tags: mql4

I am trying to create an expert advisor ( EA ) that would limit the number of open symbol to 3

For example, if I load the EA on 15 different symbols, it would not open a trade on more than 3 at any particular time. Below is the code I inserted in the EA but not working as I want:

```
int SYMBOL_NUMBER_LIMIT = 3;
string COUNTED_SYMBOLS[];

ArrayResize(COUNTED_SYMBOLS, SYMBOL_NUMBER_LIMIT, 0);

for(int s=0; s<SYMBOL_NUMBER_LIMIT; s++) COUNTED_SYMBOLS[s]="";

int  SYMBOLS_IN_TRADE_SO_FAR = 0;
bool NEW_TRADE_PERMISSION = true;
int  ALL_POSITIONS =  OrdersTotal(); // PositionsTotal();

if(ALL_POSITIONS > 0)
{
    for(int index=0; index<ALL_POSITIONS; index++)
    {
            string THIS_SYMBOL = OrderSymbol(); // PositionGetSymbol(index);
            bool   Symbol_already_counted = false;

            for(int i=0; i<SYMBOL_NUMBER_LIMIT; i++)
            {
                    if(COUNTED_SYMBOLS[i]==THIS_SYMBOL)
                    {
                            Symbol_already_counted = true;
                            break;
                    }
            if(Symbol_already_counted) continue;
            else
            {
                    SYMBOLS_IN_TRADE_SO_FAR++;
                    if(SYMBOLS_IN_TRADE_SO_FAR >= SYMBOL_NUMBER_LIMIT)
                    {
                            NEW_TRADE_PERMISSION = false;
                            break;
                    }
                    for(int j=0; j<SYMBOL_NUMBER_LIMIT; j++)
                    if(COUNTED_SYMBOLS[j]=="")
                    {
                            COUNTED_SYMBOLS[j] = THIS_SYMBOL;
                            break;
                    }
            }
    }
}
 }
```

I would appreciate any help to make it work as I described. Thanks in advance

Comment: it is not clear whether this function is called in OnInit() or in OnTick() and how you call this function. Please provide more code to understand your problem